# 'extend' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'd'

Tags: kql

I'm struggling with the following problem in KQL,

```
let a = 1;
let b = 2;
let c = DeviceInfo
| take 3
| count
| project-rename c=Count;
let d = DeviceInfo
| take 4
| count
| project-rename d=Count;
c | extend a,b
```

This produce the following result

```
| c | a | b |
-------------
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
```

By changing the last line, I'm able to get `a,b,d`  but I'm unable to get `a,b,c,d`  in the same table. I get the

```
'extend' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'd'
```

Any clues ? How can we use multiples `let` variable who come from results in a single table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this simplified and clearer version, using [`toscalar()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/toscalarfunction):

```
let a = 1;
let b = 2;
let c = toscalar(
    DeviceInfo
    | take 3
    | count
);
let d = toscalar(
    DeviceInfo
    | take 4
    | count
);
print a, b, d, c
```

Comment: Works perflectly, thanks